# Log4j Logging OutputStream chaining

Tags: java, log4j

I have a legacy Java app, It uses Log4j as logging tool. The app is lacking metrics, so I want to find a way to smartly retrieve some Java class based metrics.

The issue is, I want to intercept all Log4j logging before they are served.

The idea is inspired by the chaining of the `System.out` looking like this

```
TeeOutputStream myOut=new TeeOutputStream(System.out, mySpecificOut);
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(myOut, true); //true - auto-flush after println
System.setOut(ps);
```

So is there a way to chain the Log4j output stream and fully control it on Java because I need to do some logic before logging.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, you can define your own Stream using

```
LoggingOutputStream extends OutputStream {
```

and chain in order to intercept the logs

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new LoggingOutputStream(
```

Have a look at [this nice example](https://sysgears.com/articles/how-to-redirect-stdout-and-stderr-writing-to-a-log4j-appender/) based on innoq/log4j [LoggingOutputStream](https://github.com/innoq/log4j/blob/master/contribs/JimMoore/LoggingOutputStream.java).